# C# MonoDevelop Auto-Complete Messages Disagree with Compiler

Tags: c#, autocomplete, compiler-errors, unity-game-engine

I'm working in Unity 4.1.5f1 with MonoDevelop 2.8.2 (i.e. current Unity setup as of writing), and I'm getting a weird conflict between what auto-complete tells me, and what the compiler is telling me.

In the Unity window, which is where compiler messages show up in the Unity framework, I'm getting this message:

`Assets/Scripts/Track/Serialisation/FilePath.cs(74,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'InvalidDataException' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?`

However, auto-complete seems to understand what it is when I hover over it.

[image: Auto-complete knows where it's at, literally.]

Also, I discovered InvalidDataException using auto-complete, I didn't type it in manually.  According to Microsoft, it's there: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.invaliddataexception.aspx

Before you ask, at the top of my file I have the correct `using` statement:

```
using System.IO;
```

I've also tried a fully-qualified name:

```
catch(System.IO.InvalidDataException ex)
{
    Debug.Log(ex.Message);

    return false;
}
```

But then the compiler is even more specific in its disagreement with auto-complete:

`Assets/Scripts/Track/Serialisation/FilePath.cs(74,41): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'InvalidDataException' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO'. Are you missing an assembly reference?`

Does anybody know what's happening here?  I feel like this must be a trap for young players, but searching yields very little.  Usually when the IDE does something like this I just restart it, but that hasn't made the problem go away.

Comment: Straight from [UnityAnswers](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/509689/invaliddataexception-not-available.html?sort=oldest).

Comment: Well, dang it.  Thanks.  I don't know why I couldn't find that...

Comment: Just to answer the question in a more generic way, does that mean this problem arises when autocomplete and the compiler are looking at different versions of the framework?  I mean, theoretically you could get this problem in other compiler/IDE combinations.  Is that right?

Comment: Best guess:  It's more efficient for Monodevelop to build its autocomplete database from the full .NET library once, as opposed to rebuilding it every time you switch compatibility modes.

Comment: I guess, although I imagine switching compatibility modes isn't something you do very often.  So should I close this question, since the answer was so simple?